# FLASH AS3 pass variable from scene 1 to scene 2

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe

I was thinking if I could pass a value from a variable when I go to a next scene.
Like for example, I have Scene 1 and Scene 2.
In scene 1, I'm playing a game and ofc, I am having a score.
When the character in the game dies, it will go to the second scene.
The method I used in going to the second scene is gotoAndStop.
How can I pass the score to the second scene so I could show it in the Game over scene(scene2)?
Thanks! :))

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable or use the singleton pathern. See this answer [global variables in AS3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414733/global-variables-in-as3)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a class to store your score.

```
package file_as {//this is the package name

    public class CScore {

        public function CScore() {
            public var MyScore:int = 100;
        }

    }

}
```

And in the script,you just new it and use it.Like,`trace("CScore.MyScore")`;